# How do I call a post render function in Mozart?

Tags: jquery, dom, coffeescript, mozart-mvc

I have a Mozart app where I want to trigger a library/function call that decorates the DOM after the entire page has rendered.

In a vanilla HTML app with jQuery, I'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(-> Library.decorate())
```

In this case, I'm looking for some sort of afterRender callback or hook that will update dynamically when the view changes, rather than just apply it to `window.onload` (as the decorate call needs to fire again after DOM changes have been rendered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event **render:complete** on the Layout class that is triggered when a render cycle completes:

In your **app.coffee**, or similar:

```
App.Application = Mozart.MztObject.create()

App.Application.set 'layout', Mozart.Layout.create(
  rootElement: '#main'
  states: [
    Mozart.Route.create
    viewClass: App.HomePage
    path: "/"
    title: "Mozart"

    # ...other routes...
  ]
)

App.Application.layout.bind 'render:complete',  ->
  # Your handler code here
  Library.decorate()
```

**render:complete** only occurs when all views in a cycle have been rendered, although please bear in mind that this will be called after *every* render cycle, if your app is doing a lot of re-rendering (which you should avoid, regardless), it could end up being called a lot.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I was asking.